# Populate data into a dropdown from a stored procedure using coffeescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, coffeescript

Am new to CoffeeScript. Am building an application that uses coffeescript to build and render html pages. Am using visual studio for building the application. I have created a database and some stored procedures using SQL Server 2012.

My question is how do i fill the data into the "select" element (or a dropdown as you might call it) from a stored procedure implemented on SQL Server. From what I have read, it is not possible to call a stored procedure from javascript. How do I go about implementing this. I am trying to follow a data-driven design and do not want to fill in the options in array manually. I want it the dropdown list to fill automatically when the page loads. I tried to make an ajax call and requesting from a url that I defined in the controller. But it does not seem to work. Any help?
The reason I did not include code is because am trying to use OOP pattern and its a big code to begin with. However, for a snippet, I can provide my coffeescript code as below:

```
class NewInput
 constructor: (arg)->
    @type = arg.type
    @remove = arg.remove
    @onChangeHook = arg.onChange
    @data = arg.data ? {}
    @setInputs()
 setInputs: ->
    fields = {}
    fields.type = new SelectInput
        name: "Type"
        opts: ["All", "TV", "Computer", "Phone"]
        get: => @data.ModelType
        set: (val)=>
               @data.ModelType = val
               @onChange()
 onChange: ->
     if @validated
        @valid()
    @onChangeHook()
 valid: -> 
    @validated = true
    # Logic to check if the fields are blank or not etc.
```

Here, SelectInput is a new class that I created for creating a dropdown using coffeescript. Like I mentioned, am not using HTML to create pages. Instead am using coffeescript to create elements.

```
class SelectInput
 @draw: (arg)->
    new SelectInput(arg).draw()
 constructor: (arg)->
    @name = arg.name
    @opts = arg.opts
    @get = arg.get
    @set = arg.set
 draw: ->
    val = @get()
    select = Crt.ce "select"
    select.className = "quote-select"
    select.appendChild @genOpt
        name: @name
        dimmed: true
    for opt in @opts
        select.appendChild @genOpt
              name: opt
              selected: 
                opt == val
    @$select = $ select
    @setEvents()
    select
 setEvents: ->
    @$select.change => @change()
 change: ->
    val = @$select.val()
     val = null if val == @name
    @set val
 genOpt: (arg)->
    name = arg.name
    selected = arg.selected
    dimmed = arg.dimmed
    opt = Crt.ce "option"
    opt.className = "quote-select-option"
    opt.className += " dimmed" if dimmed
    Crt.atn opt, name
    opt.value = name
    opt.setAttribute "selected", "selected" if selected
    opt
 isBlank: ->
    blank = @$select.val() == @name
    if blank
        @$select.addClass "invalid"
    else
        @$select.removeClass "invalid"
    blank
 forceHL: (bool)->
    return if !@$select
    if bool
        @$select.addClass "invalid"
    else
        @$select.removeClass "invalid"
```

Above, "Crt.ce" stands for createElement and "Crt.atn" stands for appendTextNode. dimmed is a class declared in css to keep the select name in different color than options.

So, my question is how do i fill the options in the "opt" array using stored Procedure. Currently, am hardcoding the array which I do not want and its not data-driven. Hope this helps a bit regarding how am approaching the problem.

Comment: You are right, you cannot access a SQL instance from browser based javascript, you need a server side lang for that. sounds like you have a lot of questions that need answering in between your understanding of the problem and the solution. maybe start by googling 'asp.net web framework' or 'node web framework'. It might be possible with a web framework like meteor.js which blurs that line a little. voting to close because this is so vague.

Comment: @JedSchneider Well, am using coffeescript for frontend. C# for middle tier(server) and SQL Server for database. The question is that am not using plain html to create select element, which would have been way easier to make since i could fill the options using data-binding. But using coffeescript, I have created an array for values for "option", which is what am trying to fill.

Comment: you can either render the select options via an html templating solution, or request them via ajax if you want to dynamically populate them. The ajax call is going to require and endpoint on you server. None of that is specific to coffeescript.

Comment: @JedSchneider Like I mentioned in the question, I have tried implementing the ajax call, and I have also defined an endpoint. Implemented that in the controller class as well. But it seems not to work. The reason I was asking about coffeescript, because if there might be a different way to do the same. Coffeescript provides some leverage when compared to JavaScript. Thus, asked pertaining to it.

Comment: coffeescript does not provide any specific library extension over the common javascript libraries. It only provides syntax support for overcoming common development patterns in javascript. I'd probably start by posting the code you have so we can see why its not working. Thats usually how SO works best.